# Upload files to my personal box account using box api java sdk

Tags: java, box-api

I would like to create a java application that automatically uploads files to my personal box account using the box api java sdk. I can save my credentials and do not want to enter them each time. I will not be uploading files on other users' behalf and hence would prefer not to use oauth. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to authenticate using OAuth2 since all of the Box API calls require an OAuth2 token in the header.

It looks like the Java SDK will auto-refresh your token when it's about to expire, so you will only need to authenticate once (unless your application restarts).